# Why does Node.js exit before completing a non-flowing stream copy

Tags: node.js

I'm just learning node.js and wanted to write a simple test program that copied a file from a source folder to a destination folder. I piped a fs.ReadStream to a fs.WriteStream and that worked perfectly. I next tried to use non-flowing mode but the following program fails 99% of the time on larger files (anything over 1MB.) I'm assuming that given certain timing the event queue becomes empty and so exits. Should the following program work?

```
var sourcePath = "./source/test.txt";
var destinationPath = "./destination/test.txt";

// Display number of times 'readable' callback fired
var callbackCount = 0;
process.on('exit', function() {
    console.log('Readable callback fired %d times', callbackCount);
})

var fs = require('fs');
var sourceStream = fs.createReadStream(sourcePath);
var destinationStream = fs.createWriteStream(destinationPath);

copyStream(sourceStream, destinationStream);

function copyStream(src, dst) {
    var drained = true;

    // read chunk of data when ready
    src.on('readable', function () {
        ++callbackCount;
        if (!drained) {
            dst.once('drain', function () {
                writeToDestination();
            });
        } else {
            writeToDestination();
        }

        function writeToDestination() {
            var chunk = src.read();

            if (chunk !== null) {
                drained = dst.write(chunk);
            }
        }
    });

    src.on('end', function () {
        dst.end();
    });
}
```

*NOTE: If I remove the drain related code the program always works but the node.js documentation indicates that you should wait on a drain event if the write function returns false.*

So should the above program work as is? If it shouldn't how should I reorganize it to work with both `readable` and `drain` events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're most of the way there; there are just a couple of things you need to change.

1. When writing to `dst` you need to keep reading from `src` until either you get a `null` `chunk`, or `dst.write()` returns `false`.
2. Instead of listening for all `readable` events on `src`, you should only be listening for those events when it's ok to write to `dst` and you currently have nothing to write.

Something like this:

```
function copyStream(src, dst) {
    function writeToDestination() {
        var chunk = src.read(),
            drained = true;

        // write until dst is saturated or there's no more data available in src
        while (drained && (chunk !== null)) {
            if (drained = dst.write(chunk)) {
                chunk = src.read();
            }
        }

        if (!drained) {
            // if dst is saturated, wait for it to drain and then write again
            dst.once('drain', function() {
                writeToDestination();
            });
        } else {
            // if we ran out of data in src, wait for more and then write again
            src.once('readable', function() {
                ++callbackCount;
                writeToDestination();
            });
        }
    }

    // trigger the initial write when data is available in src
    src.once('readable', function() {
        ++callbackCount;
        writeToDestination();
    });

    src.on('end', function () {
        dst.end();
    });
}
```